# Online GUI design tool

Tags: web-services, user-interface

Is there somewhere a web based app in which you can make a mockup for program UI? It doesn't have to export to anything meaningful, but it can't hurt.  Need to present several UI designs (as much as I can come up with) to a customer, but couldn't find any tool on the web.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find this thread either while searching before posting. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I use balsamiq mockups:

http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups

Really nice and free...

You really can make nice looking to be apps with this and it is cartoonish but very slick.
Check out how the google, youtube, and the big boy sample apps here: http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/examples#boogle

If you want to share your designs you can look at mocking bird: http://gomockingbird.com/
But to be quite honest I think you will love using balsamiq for putting together something on the fly to show to other co-workers / clients.

If you want something free and built into say firefox try [pencil](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8487)

Comment: Just the tool I wanted! Thank you. It's free, but it annoys every 5 minutes with a dialog, and it watermarks output PNG images with mockup, but that's not a problem with me.

Comment: Yes but if you are the lone developer buying one copy is not expensive for what you get.  Plus you can always use this for design specs, and future applications.

Comment: If it turns out I'll need it more than this one time, I don't mind paying for a good software (even thou I prefer open source).

Comment: I can't help voting up anything that features stackunderwear :(

Answer (score 3):

http://creately.com/Online-UI-Mockups-and-Wireframes

Answer (score 1):

[Mockup Builder](http://mockupbuilder.com) looks like it could be a very promising free alternative.

Comment: Sadly, since I wrote my original answer, Mockup Builder's free offering has been severely limited. It looks like you are now limited to three screens without paying.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of great information here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156937/do-you-know-an-alternative-to-balsamiq-mockups
(A Stack Overflow topic about alteratives to Balsamiq)