# Tool to design Layout for Android -apps online?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am trying to use DroidDraw.org for designing the user-interface, [here](http://www.droiddraw.org/), but it does not allow copying it to the clipboard. Does there exist some tool to design and copy-paste things?

[image]

Comment: Do **NOT** use AbsoluteLayout! It's deprecated because it isn't flexible for different screen sizes.

Comment: My experience is that it's easier to actually code the layout xml file manually than to use a tool for it. But that's just my preference.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I cannot help with the copy-paste -ban but the following threads poped up in SO:

- [Online GUI design tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224329/online-gui-design-tool)
- [Is there a good tool for doing Android layout design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783586/is-there-a-good-tool-for-doing-android-layout-design)
- [Layout design help Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958917/layout-design-help-android)

Comment: Perhaps interesting iOS-biased thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352083/ios-like-storyboard-tool-for-android-project).

Answer (score 1):

Open it in Chrome. Right click the text you wanna copy. Choose Inspect. You'll see the html at the bottom of the browser. Right click appropriate html and choose edit as html. Copy from there.