# What are ways to see output of xml / layout files(Views) in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, flutter

can anyone tell me where to see layout files output(Views)...Any way of doing this?? Like we have flutterstudio
Any online visualizer..??

Comment: @NileshRathod you haven't read his question.. he want to see design somewhere else

Comment: Actually its difficult to find the UI element when the project is not build but partially it is working ...

Answer (score 2):

Android visualizer is a way to do it as mentioned by other users but if you want to use android studio,create a new project. In the successfully built project, paste your `xml` to view it in designer's window.

Answer (score 0):

Current project will not show you UI until a successful build.

> If I was at your place, I would **copy** that **xml layout** to
>   **another project** or some new sample project.

If you still ask me online viewer. then try [Udacity Android Visualizer](https://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/), here is an [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13209236/6891563) too.